# How to make my C++ opensource crossplatform application update itself? (any boost libs for that?)

Tags: c++, frameworks, boost, cross-platform

I have an app. It is cross platform. It is not any way enterprise nor it has more than 500 users. So no one really wants to do anything bad to it. It has 3 packets available via http in some source repository manager like Google code for Mac OS Windows and Linux. I need my app to check for updates and download them and replace current executables/files around, restart app. As for me - I see a way like to distribute 2 applications - one that checks for updates or runs currently existing executable and executable itself... I wonder what is really used and are there any boost libs for that or any other cross platform libs for such stuff?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use a startup script. The script checks to see if it is the latest version if not it downloads the latest version. Once we know we have the latest version start the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a cross platform solution to automatic updates.
They didn't seem to be able to find any here: [How can I enable auto-updates in a Qt cross-platform application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077550/how-can-i-enable-auto-updates-in-a-qt-cross-platform-app)